# "Parameter index out of range" when saving new parent+child entities (manyToOne)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Trying to save parent entity with set of children. Child entity has a composite pk.

Key:

```
class Key implements Serializable {
    Long workId;
    Long id; 
}
```

Child entity — Worker

```
@Data
@Entity
@IdClass(Key.class)
@Table(name = "workers")
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Worker {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "work_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long workId;

    @Id
    @Column
    private Long id; // id of worker's profession (doesn't matter) 

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "work_id")
    private Work work;

    private String name;
}
```

Parent entity — Work

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "works")
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"workers"})
public class Work {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "work", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Worker> workers = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}
```

When I try to save entities...:

```
Work work = new Work();
Worker worker = new Worker();
worker.setWork(work);
worker.setId(666); // doesnt matter
worker.setName("Joe");
work.getWorkers().add(worker);
workRepository.save(work);
```

I go the following exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [ru.burmistr.service.economy.features.works.entities.HouseWorkWorker]; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [ru.burmistr.service.economy.features.works.entities.HouseWorkWorker]
 
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [ru.burmistr.service.economy.features.works.entities.HouseWorkWorker]; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [ru.burmistr.service.economy.features.works.entities.HouseWorkWorker]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:407) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(DefaultJpaDialect.java:127) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:545) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:534) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:305) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at ru.burmistr.service.economy.features.works.services.HouseWorkService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$825e705b.add(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at ru.burmistr.service.economy.features.works.HouseWorkController.add(HouseWorkController.java:78) ~[classes/:na]
    at ru.burmistr.service.economy.features.works.HouseWorkController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$90569426.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at ru.burmistr.service.economy.features.works.HouseWorkController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f1dc012f.add(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [ru.burmistr.service.economy.features.works.entities.HouseWorkWorker]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:511) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3290) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2486) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:532) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 112 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [ru.burmistr.service.economy.features.works.entities.HouseWorkWorker]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3194) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3690) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1454) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    ... 121 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (7 > number of parameters, which is 6).
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.checkBounds(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1365) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.getCoreParameterIndex(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1378) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.setLong(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1573) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor221.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.22.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy133.setLong(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeSet(ComponentType.java:333) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrateId(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2921) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2879) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3167) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    ... 128 common frames omitted
```

And the log:

```
2021-07-27 13:23:02.452 DEBUG 57490 --- [nio-8004-exec-9] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into houses_works_professions (amount, cost, house_work_id, qualification, rank, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into houses_works_professions (amount, cost, house_work_id, qualification, rank, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2021-07-27 13:23:02.453 TRACE 57490 --- [nio-8004-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [FLOAT] - [0.0]
2021-07-27 13:23:02.453 TRACE 57490 --- [nio-8004-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [NUMERIC] - [0]
2021-07-27 13:23:02.453 TRACE 57490 --- [nio-8004-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [18]
2021-07-27 13:23:02.453 TRACE 57490 --- [nio-8004-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [INTEGER] - [4]
2021-07-27 13:23:02.453 TRACE 57490 --- [nio-8004-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as [INTEGER] - [1]
2021-07-27 13:23:02.453 TRACE 57490 --- [nio-8004-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [6] as [BIGINT] - [null]
2021-07-27 13:23:02.453 TRACE 57490 --- [nio-8004-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [7] as [BIGINT] - [92]
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace.

Comment: @JensSchauder here it is https://pastebin.com/wamXjRM4
some entities has been renamed, but still clear to understand, hope so

Comment: As you can see from the log, the insert causing the problems, does not come from inserting Workers. Please post the relevant classes. Please edit your question this time, instead of linking to it on third party sites.